# MySQL return rows above and below a specific answer

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table of simple data that contains three columns, an Id, the persons name and the a related sales figure. I can't figure how to return the above and below row when ranked by Sales figures.

```
id | Name | Sales
---|------|------
0  | Tim  | 9
1  | Jim  | 5
2  | Joe  | 3
3  | Ryan | 6
4  | Phil | 7
5  | James| 1
```

So, for example, the user Ryan, has a total sales of 6. How would I return Jim, who has 5 sales, below him[Ryan] and then Phil above him[Ryan] with 7. I've tried a few queries and even splitting it into two. With the query, this result if outputted:

```
id | Name | Sales
---|------|------
4  | Phil | 7
3  | Ryan | 6
1  | Jim  | 5



select * from SalesFigures where id >= '3' LIMIT 2 ORDER BY Sales ASC
```

This errors, and in theory would only return the row queried and the one below it.

How would this outcome be achieved? As I can't seem to order by the Sales figure.

Thanks.

Comment: `ORDER BY Sales DESC` ?

Comment: The error results due to `id >= '3'`, since id is a number not a string... Strip away the quotes: `id >= 3`

Comment: I get the following error without quote and with quotes: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY Sales DESC' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
SELECT SalesFigures.*
FROM
  SalesFigures INNER JOIN (
  SELECT s1.Sales v1, MAX(s2.Sales) v2, MIN(s3.Sales) v3
  FROM
    SalesFigures s1 LEFT JOIN SalesFigures s2
    ON s1.Sales > s2.Sales
    LEFT JOIN SalesFigures s3
    ON s1.Sales < s3.Sales
  WHERE
    s1.ID =3) m ON SalesFigures.Sales IN (m.v1, m.v2, m.v3)
```

Using a UNION query will look something like this:

```
SELECT SalesFigures.*
FROM SalesFigures WHERE ID=3
UNION ALL
(SELECT SalesFigures.*
 FROM SalesFigures INNER JOIN SalesFigures s
      ON SalesFigures.Sales < s.Sales
 WHERE s.ID = 3
 ORDER BY SalesFigures.Sales DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT SalesFigures.*
 FROM SalesFigures INNER JOIN SalesFigures s
      ON SalesFigures.Sales > s.Sales
 WHERE s.ID = 3
 ORDER BY SalesFigures.Sales LIMIT 1)
```

But while this will work on sample data, if there are multiple rows with the same Sales value it will return only one.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you are getting an error because the `LIMIT` clause has to come after the `ORDER BY` one.  In your example they are the wrong way around, but the order of the clauses in SQL is important.

Using a UNION I would do it like this:

```
(SELECT id, name, sales
FROM salesfigures
WHERE sales = (SELECT MIN(sales) FROM salesfigures 
   WHERE sales > (SELECT sales FROM salesfigures where id=3)))
UNION
(SELECT id, name, sales
FROM salesfigures
WHERE sales = (SELECT sales FROM salesfigures WHERE id=3))
UNION
(SELECT id, name, sales
FROM salesfigures
WHERE sales = (SELECT MAX(sales) FROM salesfigures 
   WHERE sales < (SELECT sales FROM salesfigures where id=3)))
```

Somewhat ugly with nested subselect statements, but it combines three select statements to find those with a sales figure immediately greater than equal to, and lesser than the user with an ID of 3.

In the first statement it finds the sales figure for ID 3 (Ryan), then uses this in a SELECT statement to find the minimum value higher it, which is then used in a SELECT statement to return all entires with that sales figure.  The third statement obviously being the reverse (maximum value below Ryan's).  The middle statement simply finds the sales figure for ID 3 (Ryan) then returns anything with the same.  The order of the statements in the union means it will be sorted in descending order as per your example.  But if the sales figures are not unique it could return something like:

```
id | Name   | Sales
---|--------|------
12 | George | 7
4  | Phil   | 7
9  | Pat    | 6
23 | Tony   | 6
3  | Ryan   | 6
1  | Jim    | 5
```

It depends on how you want to handle situations where the sales figures are not unique, and how you want to secondary sort them.